# CSS display not inheriting when using float

Tags: css, inheritance, css-float

I am using Zurb Foundation and have an element with `display: inherit !important;`. I can't (well at least shouldn't) change this rule, as it is part of Foundation.

I want this element to have the same display as its parent, which is `inline-block`. However, its parent has property `float: right`, which seems to stop the child from inheriting its `display` property.

I wrote a basic example: **http://jsfiddle.net/ew1fkps2/1/**

HTML:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        <div class="c">
            I should have display: inline-block;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a {
    display: block;
}
.b {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
.c {
    display: inherit !important;
}
```

I have tried adding numerous properties suggested in other threads with similar (but different) problems (`overflow: hidden`, `position: relative`...), but nothing fixed it.

So my question is why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: The `float` property makes the computed display value `block`...so that is what is being inherited. Why are you using `inline-block` on a floated div? And what is it you are trying to achieve? - http://jsfiddle.net/ew1fkps2/3/

Comment: I don't know if i understood your question...you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ew1fkps2/2/

Comment: @Paulie_D I want the `.c` div to have `display: inline-block`, since on my website there are other divs next to it which I want to display on the same line. With `display: block` they are (obviously) displayed below each other. I want something exactly like @user3760661 posted, but without using something hacky like `!important` (if it's possible of course).

Comment: Then float the `c` divs - http://jsfiddle.net/ew1fkps2/6/

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks! That worked perfectly. Maybe you could add this as an answer so I can mark it as answered.

Comment: @WouterFlorijn Happy to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, the `float` property makes the computed display value `block`...so that is what is being inherited.

See: [**Float @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Rather than try to use `display:inline-block`  on the required children, just float them also...as follows:

```css
.a {
  display: block;
}
.b {
  float: right;
  background: red;
}
.c {
  background: #f06d06;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">I'm floated</div>
    <div class="c">So am I</div>
    <div class="c">Me too.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the properties `display`, `float` and `position` interact:

> [**9.7 Relationships between 'display', 'position', and 'float'**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)
>
> The three properties that affect box generation and layout —
>   'display', 'position', and 'float' — interact as follows:
>
> 1. If ['display'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) has the value 'none', then ['position'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position) and ['float'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-float) do not apply. In this case, the element generates no box.
> 2. Otherwise, if ['position'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position) has the value 'absolute' or 'fixed', the box is absolutely positioned, the computed value of ['float'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-float)
>      is 'none', and display is set according to the table below. The
>      position of the box will be determined by the ['top'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-top),
>      ['right'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-right), ['bottom'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-bottom) and ['left'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-left) properties and the box's
>      containing block.
> 3. Otherwise, if 'float' has a value other than 'none', the box is floated and 'display' is set according to the table below.
> 4. Otherwise, if the element is the root element, 'display' is set according to the table below, except that it is undefined in CSS
>      2.1 whether a specified value of 'list-item' becomes a computed value of 'block' or 'list-item'.
> 5. Otherwise, the remaining ['display'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) property values apply as specified.
>
> ```
> Specified value                            | Computed value
> ===============================================================
> inline-table                               | table
> ---------------------------------------------------------------
> inline, table-row-group, table-column,     | block
> table-column-group, table-header-group,    |
> table-footer-group, table-row, table-cell, |
> table-caption, inline-block                |
> ---------------------------------------------------------------
> others                                     | same as specified
> ```

In your case, the third case applies. So, according to the table, a `display` of `inline-block` computes to `block`.